# Setting up ubuntu VM on Azure with apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

In Azure, I created a virtual network and then associated an Ubuntu Server virtual machine, created with Azure Resource Manager Deployment method, with the network. I then updated the associated Network Security Group and added an inbound security rule for port 80 (Source:Any, Destination:Any, Service:TCP/80). After installing Apache on the VM, I tried to access the server from my browser, but have run into a wall. I can SSH into the VM just fine, but web is a no-go, and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes happen to me too because I forgot to RESTART the VM, yes just restart it. At least this works for me. and also dont forget to add outbound rule too

Comment: The NSG will need both inbound and outbound rules?

Comment: well, not really, but you can try it just to be safe

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem

Comment: Sorry I hadn't gotten back to you. I did try setting up the outbound rule and  restarting the VM, but I get the same result. I can't see what could be causing the problem, so I'll likely end up trying the classic deployment model as a stop-gap while I get the new method figured out.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with this [inbound rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co8LU.png).

Note that when a VM is created from the portal (in ARM model), it gets automatically associated to a virtual network (vnet), a specific subnet within the vnet and a network security group.

When creating the inbound security rule, make sure to:

- [identify the correct network security group associated to the VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLgL6.png)
- use a priority number lower than 65500
- set the source port range as `*`

Answer (score 0):

You also need open port 80 on the VM to allow web access.
I dont think that creating your Network Security Group opens the desired port on the VM automatically.

Comment: That worked for me in the classic deployment model, but, using the Resource Manager deployment model, I don't see that there is a way to create endpoints in the VM settings. As far as I can tell, the VM should inherit rules from the associated NSG. Are you saying I should be able to open the port in the VM as well?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read the question correct, no idea why it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

By default in Azure Resource Manager (ARM), all ports are open; there is no need to make Network Security Groups (NSGs) to open ports, only to close them. Here is an example of an ARM template that deploys an ubuntu VM with apache:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/apache2-on-ubuntu-vm

Alternatively, if you want an auto-scaling LAP stack using VM Scale Sets (in public preview), you can find the ARM template for that here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-lapstack-autoscale

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I haven't touched templates much, but I'll look into this.