# Apache server not reachable inside Azure VM

Tags: apache, azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying create a simple web server inside Azure using SQLite as a database and PHP with Apache as a backend. I was able to create a VM in the new portal, access it with SSH, git clone the software inside it, and add an Inbound security rule to port 80. Still my application is not accessible on my browser. Is there any other configuration I am missing?

Here are the steps I did on azure portal:

- Virtual Machines -> Add -> Chose ubuntu server 14.04, and deployment model "Resource Manager", clicked on Create.
- Filled in a name, username to connect to the vm, password authentication, created a new resource group, and the location closer to me (Brazil South).
- Selected "A0 Basic" size
- On settings I clicked on "network security group", and added a new rule for port 80, with priority 1010.
- Finally on summary I clicked OK and waited for about 4-5 min to the console show me an OK message.
- After that I log into the VM with ssh, ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install apache2`.
- When I type the public IP of the VM in the browser, it just keeps loading forever but doesn't show anything. Neither and error, nor the apache default page.

Comment: did you make sure apache is running? sudo service apache2 status. if it's running, can you make sure your default config file is in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory and configured correctly?

Comment: Checked that right now. Console returned it is running.

Comment: Check the file if it's in sites-available, and if it is, please double check the inbound rule you entered, make sure to open the ports in the correct way, because with what you're seeing, most probably you didnt open port 80 correctly.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your inbound rule.

Comment: It worked! As suggested on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34499645/1718174, I changed the port from 80 to * and it is now working (but I have no ideia why!). This seems like a bug on Azure to me.