# Website is down after the Azure VM restarted

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

We have a website deployed on apache (Ubuntu machine). After we restarted(stopped and started) the VM the website went down.
The website is written in PHP/Codeigniter

I have started the apache by:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

this is the status:

```
Feb 15 22:10:53 ***** systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 15 22:10:53 *****  systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

We did not change anything in configs. I Never touched the codebase.
Checked the Apps Service, it is running well.

Any idea where to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here [Troubleshoot application connectivity issues on virtual machines in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-app-connection),
and this [Apache server not reachable inside Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728655/apache-server-not-reachable-inside-azure-vm) maybe is helpful

Comment: Thanks, I had to change the IP in DNS zones. It had been changed after the restart of the VM.